# Play / Pause Audio Upon Button Click Without Delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-audio

I'm looking for a way to make html5 audio play as soon as button is clicked. Right now, it does work; but not very reliably.

My file is a 300Kb MP3 (128Kbps) that is hosted on AWS Cloudfront.

```
<audio id="i-audio" src="https://cdn/url/to/i-audio.mp3" preload="auto" type="audio/mp3"></audio>
```

```js
this.iAudio = document.getElementById('i-audio');

$("#button").on('click', function() {
  this.iAuido.play();
});
```

I learn that `play()` will return a promise; and I'm not sure how can I be sure that audio plays all the time; reliably.

Right now, the play would work at random times or just throw an error.

Comment: Try calling `iAudio.load()` on page load to force the source to be pre-loaded before you start playing it

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan or add the `autoplay` attribute and pause it on the `onload` event

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - does not work. I get `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException` error.

Comment: also "this" might be a different "this" when you're inside a (anonymous in this case) function

Comment: I would usually say "var context = this;" and use context inside the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're getting error messages about Promises and `.play()`, you'll need to treat `.play()` as a Promise, see this [article](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/03/play-returns-promise).

- I didn't see any `button#button` so I'm assuming that's just a typo.
- `this` has no context so it'll be referencing `window` (very useless)

  ```
  this.iAudio = document.getElementById('i-audio');
  ```

  A variable (like `var iAudio = ...` or `const iAudio = ...`) should've been declared.
- `this` has context of the element listening to the click event

  ```
  $("#button").on('click', function() {
    this.iAuido.play();
  });
  ```

  Can't imagine that this code worked even randomly it just gets worse as I read the next line. Let's assume `iAudio` is correct and references the `<audio>` tag, but for some reason `this` is prefixed to it (wHy?!?). `this` would reference the button so every segment of a line of code is all sorts of wrong.

```js
const playback = (e) => {
  const mp3 = $('.mp3')[0];
  let action = mp3.paused || mp3.ended ? mp3.play() : mp3.pause();
  return action;
}

playback().then(() => console.log('Promise Resolved')).catch(error => $('.btn').on('click', playback));
```

```css
button {
  font-size: 5rem;
  color: cyan;
  border: 0;
  background: none;
  cursor: pointer
}

button:focus {
  outline: none
}

button:hover {
  color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<audio class="mp3" src="https://glsbx.s3.amazonaws.com/-/dd.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>
<button class='btn' type='button'>&#9654;</button>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```